# Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2)

Tags: android, gradle

After update Android Studio I cant run my app - I get this Exception:

```
Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 1.0.0-rc4.
```

This is my buld.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
}
```

**UPDATE** I changed in build.gradle and now I get this error:

```
Error:(42, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes: The project 'drivernotes-android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

**UPDATE 2**
This is my build.gradle (fragment):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
signingConfigs {
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your classpath. Currently I've got:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'
```

Edit:

**Replace** runProguard with minifyEnabled in your gradle build file

Answer (score 4):

Use this version of gradle plugin

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'
```

For more info related to gradle plugin and android studio compatiblity refer [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)

Edit

As of now both android studio as well as gradle plugin are both stable hence use this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

In App build.gradle in buildTypes{} i think you using runproguard. **runProguard** is **depreceated** so use **minifyEnabled** instead of runproguard

**Edited :**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

**update answer**

```
buildTypes {    
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - you can help me? I update my answer and add build.gradle.

Comment: i said to change runproguard to minifyEnabled see my edited answer

Comment: Error:(42, 0) Cannot invoke method proguardFiles() on null object after change

Answer (score 0):

Seems like these answers are very old, here is figured out the way to to fix the problem,

From AndriodStudio, 
Step1: Cntrl+Alt+Shift => "S", will open a "Project Structure" window, 
-or-
File > Project Structure 
Step2: choose "Project" from the left array. 
Step3: Change the gradlew version here.

[image]